# Не удалось найти IP-адрес сервера venusclan.com

Tags: dns

понятия не имею в чём проблема. Нет соединения с сайтом.

Не удалось найти IP-адрес сервера venusclan.com.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Ещё вчера всё работало, проверил ip в самом домене и в настройках apache, за ночь ничего не изменилось. Перезагружал apache, удалял в DNS IP машины и заново прописал, не работает. У себя на ПК в файле hosts прописал ip и домен, тогда работает.

Главное остальные сайты работают, например boosteam.ru, или csfile.ru, они все на одной машине стоят.

Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что я не создал папку для логов сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Ответственные :) сервера зоны .com не знают ничего про этот домен.
Пинайте регистратора домена.

Comment: Я написал в тех поддержку, но не отвечают. Я всё равно не могу понять почему так получилось, ведь уже неделю работал всё хорошо, а тут. Как регистратор мог так допустить. А если бы это был например онлайн магазин, целый день простоя ну такое себе.

Comment: @ДмитрийМовсесян о, пробило. Молча что-то там исправили :)

Comment: Я так ничего и не справил, через несколько часов заработало. А или я забыл создать папку для логов нового сайта, из за это все сайты не работали :D